# Convert ajax response to an ol3 GML Layer

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers-3, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am experimenting with OpenLayers3 and am having difficulty with a getfeatureinfo request.  I'm trying to do it via ajax and convert the response to a GML layer as you could in OpenLayers2.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$.ajax({url: GeoServerURL,
     data: params,
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function (response) {
         console.log('Success!');
         var gmlLayer = new ol.format.GML({
             featureNS: 'http://www.swansea.gov.uk/',
             featurePrefix: 'ccs',
             geometryName: 'geom',
             extractAttributes: true
        });
        var results = gmlLayer.writeFeatures(response.responseText);
        if (results.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

I know that ajax gives me the correct response and in openlayers 2 I would have used the command:

```
results = gmlLayer.read(response.responseText);
```

This is what I get returned from the getFeatures request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
    xmlns:ccs="http://www.swansea.gov.uk" 
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd http://www.swansea.gov.uk http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.0.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=ccs%3Aadopted_roads">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700">
                <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
                    270089.11056331,200461.58772218 270347.13150541,200552.92157813
                </gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Box>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:featureMember>
            <ccs:adopted_roads fid="adopted_roads.277">
                <gml:boundedBy>
                    <gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700">
                        <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
                            270089.11056331,200461.58772218 270347.13150541,200552.92157813
                        </gml:coordinates>
                    </gml:Box>
                </gml:boundedBy>
                <ccs:map_no>
                    sn7000              
                </ccs:map_no>
                <ccs:text>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                </ccs:text>
                <ccs:date_of_adoption>                    
                </ccs:date_of_adoption>
                <ccs:photo>     
                </ccs:photo>
                <ccs:gid>
                    277
                </ccs:gid>
                <ccs:geom>
                    <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#27700">
                        <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
                                    270347.13150541,200511.81334524 270345.96895179,200512.03328229 270344.54255622,200511.9333109 270343.33053224,200511.71337386 270340.23863433,200510.91360279 270337.84756661,200509.77392902 270335.37404828,200507.98444126 270330.08896411,200505.44516811 270329.36339874,200504.63539991 270328.26680561,200503.26579195 270325.94169838,200500.78650164 270324.45758738,200499.2369452 270321.40691477,200495.96788096 270313.44218575,200487.21038777 270309.64121258,200483.05157821 270306.49159924,200479.40262271 270301.6682385,200473.55429678 270298.64230107,200470.08528977 270296.72120184,200468.26581059 270292.31833921,200464.00702966 270290.79300291,200462.78737878 270288.72349257,200461.93762202 270286.92606925,200461.58772218 270285.91192673,200461.61771359 270283.74347566,200461.9576163 270283.35595779,200461.99760485 270281.70694557,200462.6874074 270279.65392536,200463.65712981 270261.8610835,200472.52459153 270260.59134409,200473.20439694 270252.4287336,200473.62427675 270252.1319114,200473.42433398 270240.30849378,200473.37434829 270238.22249332,200474.0541537 270237.4227224,200472.15469741 270235.61705402,200472.65455433 270233.5228085,200472.35464018 270228.51805641,200470.55515528 270219.42375401,200475.2538103 270217.21407764,200477.03330093 270211.26938859,200480.25237947 270204.08794037,200486.07071399 270200.89710172,200488.10013308 270194.69681577,200498.39718558 270176.20314372,200513.61283014 270174.00171241,200511.61340247 270157.14056246,200522.86018312 270148.39255263,200528.24864069 270139.18281938,200533.63709826 270137.58327752,200534.7167892 270133.38654142,200536.48628268 270126.42770985,200538.71564454 270118.99066474,200540.70507507 270112.65845782,200541.90473167 270104.19902513,200545.26377016 270101.60183088,200545.26377015 270100.20841555,200545.53369289 270096.01167945,200545.33375012 270089.11056331,200540.91501497 270091.08937798,200550.74220197 270094.14005058,200551.94185857 270103.38276408,200552.32174983 270103.77852701,200552.92157813 270114.67849779,200552.12180706 270123.97892671,200550.02240801 270126.74102218,200549.46256826 270136.7835066,200546.92329512 270143.0579981,200544.7539161 270145.96850466,200543.25434535 270146.9991373,200543.00441689 270154.9061509,200537.10610526 270180.06183232,200520.26092715 270188.10901195,200514.81248675 270216.34834622,200490.5294377 270219.67935091,200488.76994135 270232.79724312,200484.86106025 270236.65593172,200483.41147519 270239.97869134,200481.81193306 270243.35092133,200480.78222781 270246.55000504,200480.28237089 270248.94931782,200479.68254259 270249.74908874,200479.62255976 270256.14725616,200479.58257121 270257.35103508,200479.98245674 270258.95057693,200480.48231365 270261.34988971,200480.78222781 270262.1166804,200480.34235372 270262.79277541,200479.70253686 270265.49715545,200476.98331523 270279.73637597,200469.38549009 270281.70694557,200468.26581059 270283.8836417,200467.41605384 270285.5161638,200466.87620836 270286.57977668,200466.74624557 270287.15693096,200466.68626273 270287.62689944,200466.79623126 270290.91667882,200468.48574764 270291.42787261,200469.14555877 270291.65873432,200469.59543 270292.59867129,200470.68511807 270302.7483415,200481.83192733 270308.78372623,200488.43003864 270313.2195691,200493.2686536 270313.58235179,200493.9984447 270316.66600464,200497.66739448 270319.79912786,200501.39632708 270322.58595851,200504.38547145 270324.6224886,200506.6148333 270328.10190439,200510.40374873 270326.61779339,200514.65253253 270341.45890337,200521.41059806 270347.13150541,200511.81334524
                            </gml:coordinates>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </ccs:geom>
        </ccs:adopted_roads>
    </gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

What I'm trying to do is read the response and write this into a popup but I'd like the response as a GML feature.

Comment: Are you trying to read or write the GML, as you have writeFeatures in your OL3 example and read in OL2?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could post a snippet of what comes back from the Geoserver WFS request.

Comment: Thanks i've added the ajax respose i think i'm trying to write the respose to a GML feature and then read it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the request is formated with json as the return format.  This works well in ol3.

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

    bounds = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())
    var params = {
        request: "GetFeatureInfo",
        exceptions: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
        bbox: bounds.join(','),
        x: parseInt(evt.pixel[0], 10),
        y: parseInt(evt.pixel[1], 10),
        info_format: 'application/json',
        query_layers: getLayers(),
        feature_count: 70,
        buffer: 5,
        srs: 'EPSG:27700',
        layers: getLayers(),
        styles: '',
        width: map.getSize()[0],
        height: map.getSize()[1]
    };
    $.ajax({url: GeoServerURL,
        data: params,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            //I couldn't get the response to be read as a GML file so changed it to geoJSON 
            Results = response;
            if (response.features.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            setPopup(response,evt,0);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If server is Geoserver (I'm assuming it's true) you can add `&outputFormat=application/json` to url and get answer in GeoJson.

Comment: Thanks changing the returned format to json works. I'll update my code with the result.